# python - filling formulas containing JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, python

I tried to fill this form:
http://bips.u-strasbg.fr/GPAT/
using Python. Unfortunately, it is written partially in JavaScript, so I couldn't do this with Mechanize. What is the best way to do this?

The problematic fragment of code:

```
<div style="width:150px; float:left">
Species:<br>
                        <input type="radio"  name="espece" value="human" onClick="Human(this.form, this.form.genome_assembly)" /> Human
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio"  name="espece" value="mouse" OnClick="Mouse(this.form, this.form.genome_assembly)" /> mouse
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio"  name="espece" value="zebrafish" OnClick="zebrafish(this.form, this.form.genome_assembly)" /> zebrafish
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio"  name="espece" value="thaliana" OnClick="thaliana(this.form, this.form.genome_assembly)" /> A. thaliana
            <br>
                        <input type="radio"  name="espece" value="melanogaster" OnClick="melanogaster(this.form, this.form.genome_assembly)" /> D. melanogaster

                    </div>
```

Comment: Disassemble the JavaScript or use Selenium to run an actual browser that supports JS.

Comment: Thank you, Blender. I tried Selenium, but new problems have appeared. Could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133395/selenium-cant-select-a-file-tried-send-keys-and-javascript-execution